# Get the profile picture with the Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook

I would like to get the profile picture. Can I do that with the [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation), and how?

When I use the Api.get option I get a jsonreader exception.

Answer (score 14):

You can render the photo by just doing:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/**id**/picture"/>
```

in your page (obviously changing the id to the id of the user).

You don't have to retrieve it using the API, but you do have to retrieve the id.

You can also get pictures by their id using /photoid like so /98423808305

You can find more information here - [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Comment: This is obsolete at 2020